# Draw dynamic horizontal line that touches the high and low of the current price

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to draw a dynamic horizontal line that touches the high and low of the current price in pinescript. Dynamic means the line will shift in real-time according to price changes.

I am using pinescript v5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create dynamic lines using `line.new()` function.
If you want to see the line only on latest bar, you can attach the new line to a series variable and then delete previous line on each bar:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
highLine = line.new(bar_index - 1, high, bar_index, high, extend = extend.both, color = color.green)
lowLine = line.new(bar_index - 1, low, bar_index, low, extend = extend.both, color = color.red)
line.delete(highLine[1])
line.delete(lowLine[1])
```